# display alert on list view tap code behind only Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi guys I have a listview that I have made in Xamarin but not using Xamarin Forms. when I tap on a selected item it turns orange by default but I want to show a DisplayAlert when I tap on it. does anybody know how to solve this? below is my list view in C#

```
public string PhoneNumber;
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

        _listView = new ListView
        {

            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {

                Label nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                nameLabel.FontSize = 20;
                Label addressLabel = new Label();
                addressLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Address");
                Label phoneLabel = new Label();
                phoneLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Phone");

                PhoneNumber = phoneLabel.Text;

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(20, 5),
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children =
                        {

                            new StackLayout
                            {
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                                Spacing = 0,
                                Children =
                                {
                                    nameLabel,
                                    addressLabel,
                                    phoneLabel,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            })
        };
        _listView.HasUnevenRows = true;

        _listView.ItemsSource = db.Table<Company>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        stackLayout.Children.Add(_listView);
        _listView.ItemTapped += _listView_ItemTapped;

        Content = stackLayout;

    }
    private void _listView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
        if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
            phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("11112222");
        DisplayAlert("Phone Dial","Dialing" + e.Item.PhoneNumber, "Ok");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create `ItemTapped` method

```
_listView.ItemTapped += _listView_ItemTapped;
```

And implement it

```
private void _listView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item as Company; //Company is your model class
    DisplayAlert("Alert", item.Name, "Cancel");
}
```

Output screen

[image]

Comment: ok that is great and my last question is i want to get the phoneLabel text on that displayalert not sure how i do that

Comment: `e.Item.PhoneNumber`. I am thinking this way you can get it. Please check once.

Comment: Nope it saying it is wrong i have updated my code to show you how it looks

Comment: It is just displaying the name instead of the phone

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change .Name to .Phone

Comment: @SodiKZ125 - What ever the fields you have in `Company` it would display those only so try to add `PhoneNumber` in `Company` class instead of declaring separately.

Comment: i have e.item.Phone But that is still showing the name only